# Modifying bootmetro template to create web commercial web site

Tags: apache, microsoft-metro

Can I  modify BootMetro template and use it to create commercial web site. Want to use css and js files created by BootMetro.
It is under below license - http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.txt

Answer (score 0):

In short, the Apache license makes no distinction on personal or commercial use, you are bound by the terms no matter how you're distributing it.

[This FAQ may help](http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html), particularly the [non-legalize writeup](http://www.apache.org/foundation/license-faq.html#WhatDoesItMEAN).  Note however that it cautions, `Describing legal documents in non-legalese is fraught with potential for misinterpretation`, so if in doubt, consult a lawyer.